Python OPC-UA : authentification
I'm trying to set up authentication for my OPC-UA server. I don't want my clients to be able to connect to my server in ‘anonymous’ mode.
So I used this configuration in my opc-ua server:

I'm testing with UaExpert in client mode and the password login works (I have to enter the right login + the right password).
The certificate login is blocked, which is fair enough.
However, I can still connect in ‘anonymous’ mode, which obviously doesn't work for me.
The logs from UaExpert when connecting in "anonymous":

I'd prefer to use the certificate authentication mode but I wanted to test the password login first.
I've tested the certificate mode and I can also connect in anonymous mode!
Does anyone have any ideas?

The python opcua library is no longer supported. There was a fix for this issue, but the pip package never got uppdated. So either use the current master from github. Or you switch to asyncua, which has a sync layer for easier porting, but i would recommend use it via async, if possible.

Hi, thank you for the answer, yes I just realized that the pip package was not updated  !
I tried with the master version from github and for the user it works fine !
I still have questions :
Is it possible to manage my certificat with python-opcua ? I mean have a similar implementation of the truststore in asyncua?  [link]https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/asyncua/crypto/truststore.py
I can't find documentation for asyncua so I don't know if I should use It, do you have some links ? And can we find example with trustore and certification managment?
thank you

Because when I use this configuration : policyIDs = ["Basic256Sha256"]         self.uaserver.set_security_IDs(policyIDs) I'm able to connect to the server with any self signed certificate, I want to be able to have a kind of "white certificate list"
@Schroeder

There is no documentation, i think. Maybe this example helps https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/server-with-encryption.py , this should contain all you want to do.

Okey i will do a test server and test the TrustStore with asyncio. Do you know if something equivalent exist for "the old" python-opcua lib ? @Schroeder
